# Difference between Inner Join VS Inner Remote Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I don't know where I have to ask this question, I just want to know what is the difference between `Inner Join` and `Inner Remote Join` ?
I have just tried implemented both joins like below:

`With Remote Inner Join`

```
SELECT P.CompanyName,u.UserName from tb_Offices AS P
INNER REMOTE JOIN 
tb_Users AS U
on P.UserId=U.UserId
```

`With Simple Inner Join`

```
SELECT P.CompanyName,u.UserName from tb_Offices AS P
INNER JOIN 
tb_Users AS U
on P.UserId=U.UserId
```

Both Queries returns same kind of records.

Then I tried run with Execution plan that is :

With `Remote Inner Join` I got :

[image]

and with simple `Inner Join` I got :

[image]

I am not so much friendly with `SQL Execution Plan`.

I just wanted to know which is better between `Inner Join` and `Inner Remote Join`.

Thanks

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: @jarlh I am using `MS SQL Server 2012`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the messages tab you will see

> Warning: The join order has been enforced because a local join hint is
>   used.

When you use the `INNER REMOTE JOIN` hint you are forcing the tables to be joined in the order as written rather than allowing it to explore all possible join permutations.

So a similar result to specifying `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)`

This explains the different execution plans.

This hint is not intended to be used for local tables.

An example where inadvertently forcing the join order this way would be extremely negative is below - as it forces the large tables A and B to be joined first before eliminating all rows with the join on C. When the optimiser is not constrained (first plan below) it reorders things to (C x A) x B and the plan is much more efficient.

```
CREATE TABLE #A(X INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE #B(X INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE #C(X INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO #A 
SELECT TOP (10000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) FROM master..spt_values v1, master..spt_values v2

INSERT INTO #B 
SELECT * FROM #A

SELECT *
FROM #A INNER JOIN #B ON #A.X = #B.X 
        INNER JOIN #C ON #A.X = #C.X 

SELECT *
FROM #A INNER REMOTE JOIN #B ON #A.X = #B.X 
        INNER JOIN #C ON #A.X = #C.X 

DROP TABLE #A, #B,#C
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks martin for your efforts..)

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use REMOTE only if the right table is on the Remote server and left is local. Also REMOTE should be used only when the left table has fewer rows than the right table.These are documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx

Comment: Is it needed if both databases provide column
distribution statistics?

Answer (score 1):

If both tables are local the "remote" hint shouldn't change anything.

In your case the difference in the execution plan comes from the columns used in the joins:

```
P.UserId=U.UserId
```

vs

```
P.fdUserId=U.fdUserId
```

Without knowing your schema, I would say that the columns in the second query aren't indexed and so require a Sort operation as they are retrieved using the order on the clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

Inner Remote join and inner join show the same result, But i suggest use Inner join instead of Inner Remote. Test it many times, it returns the same.

Answer (score 0):

Remote Join

- This is useful when the left table is a local table and the right table is a remote table.
- REMOTE should be used only when the left table has fewer rows than the right table